# .net for loop performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have this code :

```
namespace FrequencyGeneratorConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

            int from = 100000;// Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text);
            int to = 999999;//Convert.ToInt32(txtTo.Text);
            int numbers = 2000; //Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbers.Text);
            int range = 50;// Convert.ToInt32(txtRange.Text);

            var generatedFrequencies = new List<Frequency>(to - from);
            var availableRanges = new List<AvailableRange>(to - from + 1);

            //AvailableRange maxAvailableRange = new AvailableRange();

            var random = new Random();

            DateTime first = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
            {
                var frequency = new Frequency();

                if (availableRanges.Count == 0)
                {
                    frequency.Number = random.Next(from, to);
                    frequency.Number = (int)Math.Round((decimal)frequency.Number / 5) * 5;
                    int fromValue = frequency.Number - (range / 2);
                    int toValue = frequency.Number + (range / 2);

                    frequency.From = fromValue < from ? from : fromValue;
                    frequency.To = toValue > to ? to : toValue;

                    generatedFrequencies.Add(frequency);

                    var availableRange1 = new AvailableRange { From = @from, To = frequency.From };
                    availableRange1.RangeLong = availableRange1.To - availableRange1.From;
                    availableRanges.Add(availableRange1);

                    var availableRange2 = new AvailableRange { From = frequency.To, To = to };
                    availableRange2.RangeLong = availableRange2.To - availableRange2.From;
                    availableRanges.Add(availableRange2);
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
                    int max = 0, index = 0;

                    for (int j = 0; j < availableRanges.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (availableRanges[j].RangeLong > range)
                        {
                            index = j;
                        }


                    }

                    DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
                    double total1 = (d2 - d1).TotalMilliseconds;

                    AvailableRange availableRange = availableRanges[index];

                    if (availableRange.RangeLong <= range)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("there is no available pathes " + generatedFrequencies.Count);

                        break;
                    }

                    DateTime d3 = DateTime.Now;
                    double total2 = (d3 - d2).TotalMilliseconds;

                    frequency.Number = random.Next(availableRange.From + (range / 2), availableRange.To - (range / 2));
                    frequency.Number = (int)Math.Round((decimal)frequency.Number / 5) * 5;
                    int fromValue = frequency.Number - (range / 2);
                    int toValue = frequency.Number + (range / 2);

                    frequency.From = fromValue < from ? from : fromValue;
                    frequency.To = toValue > to ? to : toValue;
                    generatedFrequencies.Add(frequency);

                    var availableRange1 = new AvailableRange { From = availableRange.From, To = frequency.From, RangeLong = frequency.From - availableRange.From };
                    availableRanges.Add(availableRange1);

                    //availableRange.From = 1;


                    var availableRange2 = new AvailableRange { From = frequency.To, To = availableRange.To, RangeLong = availableRange.To - frequency.To };
                    availableRanges.Add(availableRange2);

                    //availableRange.To = frequency.From;
                    //availableRange.RangeLong = availableRange.To - availableRange.From;


                    DateTime d4 = DateTime.Now;
                    double total3 = (d4 - d3).TotalMilliseconds;

                    //availableRange.RangeLong = 0;
                    availableRanges.RemoveAt(index);

                    DateTime d5 = DateTime.Now;
                    double total4 = (d5 - d4).TotalMilliseconds;

                    double total = (d5 - d1).TotalMilliseconds;
                    if (total > 1)
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine(total + @"     :     " + total1 + @"     :     " + total2 + @"     :     " + total3 + @"     :     " + total4 +
                       //   @"    frequency     :     " + frequency.Number + @"  max    :     " + max + @"  index   :     " + index);
                    }
                }

            }
            DateTime last = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine((last - first));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class Frequency
    {
        public int From { get; set; }
        public int To { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return " from  :  " + From + " to  :  " + To + " number  :  " + Number;
        }
    }

    public class AvailableRange
    {
        public int From { get; set; }
        public int To { get; set; }
        public int RangeLong { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return " from  :  " + From + " to  :  " + To + " RangeLong  :  " + RangeLong;
        }
    }
}
```

now the problem is this code take some time
when i analyze the code i expect that some cycles take 15 milliseconds and others take 0  millisecond
if the number of  loops is small this problem does not appear 
i tried to solve this problem but i could not find the answered
what is the problem

Comment: And I suggest you use `Math.Round(... MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`. It is normally easier to comprehend, because it it the rounding they teach in schools (.5 rounds up)

Comment: thanks but the real problem not hear if you set from 1000000 and To 9999999 and numbers 20000 the problem will apear

Comment: i did the tow notes you say but the problem is still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the 16 millisecond accuracy limitation of the `System.DateTime` structure.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx.

You need to use the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class instead for any sort of performance assessment as it is usually accurate to the microsecond (depending on how much thread context switching is occurring at the time of the test).

Answer (score 2):

Not use `DateTime` for performance measure. Use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot get an accurate measurement because this is a user-mode code running in multitasking environment. Even if the thread priority is set to highest, it can be superseded by any kernel mode process.

Comment: the problem is why some cycles take 0 millisecond and other takes 15  millisecond the result is unreasonable